# Hibernate : How to get predefined object passing a String value through parameters

Tags: java, hibernate

I used following method to get predefined object .

```
public Patient getUserNameAndPassword(String username, Session session) {
        Patient patient=(Patient)session.get(Patient.class,username);
        return patient;       
}
```

After execute this method , following exception was generated .

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class beans.Patient. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
```

**PatientService.java**

```
public class PatientService {

    private static PatientDAOInterface patientDAOInterface;

    public PatientService() {
        patientDAOInterface = new PatientDAOImpl();
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        Session session = patientDAOInterface.openCurrentSession();
        return session;
    }

    public Transaction getTransaction(Session session) {
        return patientDAOInterface.openTransaction(session);
    }

    public Patient getUserNameAndPassword(String username){
        Session session = patientDAOInterface.openCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        Patient patient=new Patient();
        try{
            transaction = patientDAOInterface.openTransaction(session);
            patient=patientDAOInterface.getUserNameAndPassword(username, session);
            transaction.commit();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }        
        return patient; 
    }
}
```

**PatientDAOInterface .java**

```
public interface PatientDAOInterface 
{
    public Patient getUserNameAndPassword(String username,Session session);
    public Session openCurrentSession();
    public Transaction openTransaction(Session session);
}
```

**PatientDAOImpl.java**

```
public class PatientDAOImpl implements PatientDAOInterface {
    @Override
    public Patient getUserNameAndPassword(String username, Session session) {
        Patient patient=(Patient)session.get(Patient.class,username);
        return patient;       
    }    

    private static final SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder = SessionFactoryBuilder.getInstance();

    @Override
    public Session openCurrentSession() {

         Session currentSession =   sessionFactoryBuilder.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    return currentSession;
    }

    @Override
    public Transaction openTransaction(Session session) {

        Transaction beginTransaction = session.beginTransaction();
        return beginTransaction;
    }

}
```

I have mentioned my works above.

Actually , I want to pass a String through parameters and get a Patient object. 
I am familiar with passing an `Integer` instead of a `String`. But I have no idea about this .

Have any ideas ?

Comment: It seems like you have created a method using an integer and passing a string to get the Patient Object. Please provide more precise information on how your session.get(Patient.class, username) method works.

Answer (score 3):

You want to find a Patient by his username? Because here you are trying to find him by his ID and you are passing a String representing username. You should write your own query/criteria for getting a Patient by username. Something like this:

```java
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Patient.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username);
List<Patient> patients = criteria.list();
```

Or query version:

```java
String hql = "FROM Patient p WHERE p.username = "+username;
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List patients = query.list();
```

Comment: Ok . But I want a patient object as return type not a patient list.

Comment: List needs to be retrieved, because there may be a lot of patients with same username (at least Hibernate thinks so, it doesn't have that knowledge). Just do `return patients.get(0)`.

Comment: assuming there is no duplicate for that username, you can return patients.get(0)

Answer (score 1):

I found a answer to the problem.

```
public Patient getUserNameAndPassword(String username, Session session) {
        Query query=session.createQuery("from Patient where user_name= :username");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        List list = query.list();
        Patient patient=(Patient) list.get(0);
        return patient;
}
```

This is worked for me .

Thanks.